# Looping through (IEnumerable) results and updating, but nothing updated?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am looping thru parent records ("europe") and updating its `<Ienumerable>` field called "*childPublication*" with its child records. But the *childPublication* is null after the loop and assignment?

Here's my code:

```
foreach (var e in europe)
{
    string child = e.HasChild ?? "";
    if (child.Contains("True"))
    {
        IEnumerable<Publication> eChildrens = children.OfType<Publication>()
                                                .Where(ep => ep.ParentID.Equals(e.PublicationId));

        if (eChildrens.Count() > 0)
        {
            e.ChildPublication = eChildrens;
        }
    }
}              

member.EuropeMiddleEastAfricaPublication = europe;

public class Publication
{
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PublicationName { get; set; }
    public string PublicationFullName { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string Subscription { get; set; }
    public string ClientOnly { get; set; }
    public string PrintVersion { get; set; }
    public string EmailVersion { get; set; }
    public string RegisteredforPrint { get; set; }
    public string RegisteredforEmail { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string HasChild { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Publication> ChildPublication { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you verify that you at least end-up in the code that assigns childPublication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should debug your program and verify that you are actually getting inside your `if` and setting the property. If you aren't, then it will absolutely be null. But note that you are doing something dangerous anyway by closing over the loop variable.

```
IEnumerable<Publication> eChildrens = 
  children.OfType<Publication>().Where(ep =>  
                                         ep.ParentID.Equals(e.PublicationId)); 

if (eChildrens.Count() > 0) 
{ 
     e.ChildPublication = eChildrens; 
}
```

`eChildrens` is a lazily evaluated query and it is capturing the loop variable `e`. When you get outside the query and try to use the results, unless you have weird expectations, you code is not going to do what you want. In a closure, it is the *variable* that is captured, so your query will always be looking at the *same* `var e` when you get outside of the loop. You're going to have a lot of objects looking at the wrong `ChildPublication` sequences.

To avoid this issue, either create a local temporary variable inside the loop and close over that

```
var temp = e; // local temporary variable, used below
IEnumerable<Publication> eChildrens = 
  children.OfType<Publication>().Where(ep =>  
                                         ep.ParentID.Equals(temp.PublicationId)); 

if (eChildrens.Count() > 0) 
{ 
  e.ChildPublication = eChildrens; 
}
```

Or alternately force evaluation of the query by invoking a method such as `ToList();`

```
IEnumerable<Publication> eChildrens = 
  children.OfType<Publication>().Where(ep =>  
                                         ep.ParentID.Equals(e.PublicationId)).ToList(); 

if (eChildrens.Count() > 0) 
{ 
  e.ChildPublication = eChildrens; 
}
```

For more on this topic, please read Eric Lippert's [blog entry](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx&ei=zirYTp_PPIPxggeZnPX0Dg&usg=AFQjCNHbIUMNJBf4j0aIh0yUK2mlwB5YLQ&sig2=tnha-dhB791hM-_CMqr7uw).

Comment: Thank you for the insight, the issue required using a list.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have `eChildren = children`, so I'm assuming children is passed in somewhere?

I would probably code it something like:

```
foreach (var e in europe) 
{ 
  // .Net 4.0 use: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.HadChild)
         // I prefer IndexOf which allows Culture and IgnoreCase 
      && e.HasChild.IndexOf("True", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  { 
    IEnumerable<Publication> eChildrens = 
      children.OfType<Publication>()
              .Where(ep => ep.ParentID.Equals(e.PublicationId))
              .ToList();  //Force the IEnumeration to Enumerate.

    if (eChildrens.Count() > 0) 
    { 
      e.ChildPublication = eChildrens; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem. IEnumerable users an iterator run against your data source. Iterators return a new object, not a reference to the original object.

So, you are making changes on a copy of your original data, not your actual data. If you want to modify your original data, you need to pass a reference to it and work with that reference.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a `List<Publication>` instead or `IEnumerable<Publication>`.  I always have much more sucess with it for simple collection handling.  IEnumerable often times wants an Enumerator defined which is a little more overhead.

Comment: What overhead? Do you know that List<T> has IEnumerable<T> (among others) as base interface, thus having an enumerator too?